# Updating PHP dlls on Windows automatically

Tags: php, updates

Is there any way to automatically check if there is any update for installed php extenstions  in Windows (similar to what you do for pear classes)?

Comment: Windows won't let you update files that are in use.

Comment: @gronostaj I can stop my development server while updating.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what is the current version of PHP installed by looking at the properties of `php5.dll`

[image: Check current php5.dll version]

Go to the [PHP website](http://php.net/) to check the latest stable release. At the time of writing this answer, the latest version is 5.5.0

[Download](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.5) the latest version and update the php5.dll file

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. There are no PHP auto updaters.  The only software that gets updated automatically are Windows components managed by Windows Update, or other applications with it's own auto-updater (Java runtime environment, Adobe Reader, Google updater, etc)